# jQuery and checking a radiobutton when div scrolled to correct position

Tags: jquery, html

I have some HTML, CSS, and jQuery code. The idea is that when a radiobutton is checked, the div should be scrolled horizontally to the left position of that radiobutton.

There is a problem. If the div is scrolled to the left position of radio8, the radiobutton radio8 should be checked and I should see an alert. This does not happen.

```js
    var container = $('div'),
        scrollTo = $('#td9');

    container.animate({
      scrollLeft: scrollTo.offset().left - container.offset().left + container.scrollLeft()
    });

    $('div > input').each(function() {
      var radioInput = $(this);
      if(radioInput.is(':checked')) {
        $('div').animate({
          scrollLeft: radioInput.offset().left - $('div').offset().left + $('div').scrollLeft()
        }, 2000);
      }
    });

    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div').animate({
          scrollLeft: $(this).offset().left - $('div').offset().left + $('div').scrollLeft()
        }, 2000);
      }
    });

    // the following does not work
    container.scroll(function() {
      if(container.scrollLeft() + container.width() == $('#td8').width()) {
        $("#radio8").prop("checked", true)
        alert("reached 8!");
      }
    });
```

```css
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 70px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <table id="my_table">
        <tr>
          <td id='td1'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="1" />111111</td>
          <td id='td2'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="2" />222222</td>
          <td id='td3'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="3" />333333</td>
          <td id='td4'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="4" />444444</td>
          <td id='td5'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="5" />555555</td>
          <td id='td6'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="6" />666666</td>
          <td id='td7'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="7" />777777</td>
          <td id='td8'><input id="radio8" type="radio" name="distance" value="8" />888888</td>
          <td id='td9'><input type="radio" name="distance" value="9" checked="checked" />999999</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scrolling only dynamically

If you want to know when scrolling ends, the simplest solution is to use `complete` callback of [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to capture animation end.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.move').animate({
    scrollLeft: 200
  }, 2000, function(){
    alert('Reached!');
  });
});
```

```css
.move {
  outline: solid red;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="move">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit!</p>
</div>
```

## *ScrollSpy* method

If you want to trigger some action also when user scrolls the container by himself (without selecting `radio`), then you need to keep in mind that you shouldn't compare positions explicitely by `==`. Pixels, just like atoms, can be splitted to small pieces, so you can end up with offset `128.423px` which will never equal to `128px`. Besides, scrolling is almost always done by many pixels at once, so you need to keep some tolerance (at least +/- `5px`).

```js
$(function(){
  $('.move').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= 200) {
      alert('Reached!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.move {
  outline: solid red;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Scroll the following container by yourself:</p>
<div class="move">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, but how can I know if the scrollbar's horizontal position if more than td8's left position?

Comment: @xms, you just answered yourself! If you want to know if the position is **more than** `td8`'s position, then you need to use `>=` comparator, not `==`. Also, check out my edited answer and a *ScrollSpy* section.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 problems:

```
container.scrollLeft() + container.width() == $('#td8').width()
```

When you print these values to the console, you will see that the left hand side is always greater than the right hand side. You probably want to use `$('#td8').offset().left` instead of `.width()`.

Secondly, you compare the two sides with the equal operator. I think it is safer to use the greater than or equal operator. At least on my machine its not guaranteed that the two value will be equal, even if the scroll reaches the container right side.